# Gasoline station dataset

Tags: data.gov

I am looking for a dataset containing all US gasoline stations with addresses, similar to what is offered by http://www.allgasstations.com/ .  XML, TXT or CSV formats are best.

Comment: fyi> I looked at allgasstations.com for the Portland, OR area which is near where I live. It doesn't appear to be reliable. I would expect upwards of a 100 stations and only 2 are listed. Worse, the addresses are for Indiana instead of Oregon.

Answer (score 7):

There are several sources you could compile information from.

City data portals that list gas station locations:

**New Orleans:** https://data.nola.gov/Administrative-Data/NOLA-Gas-Stations-Map/ic3z-bztr

**Washington, DC**: https://opendata.socrata.com/dataset/Gas-Stations-in-Washington-DC/tk2x-chx8

State data portals that list alternative fuel stations:

**Oregon** (Clear Fuel): https://data.oregon.gov/Recreation/Local-clear-Gas-stations/if4z-s7kp

**Maryland** (Alternative Fuels): https://data.maryland.gov/Energy-and-Environment/Public-Electric-Vehicle-Charging-Stations-and-Alte/7yut-5ayv

The **Department of Energy** has a dataset that lists the location of 19,000 alternative fuel stations:
http://www.afdc.energy.gov/data_download

And you could do a dump from **openstreetmap** for locations of fuel stations that have been crowdsourced. This link should give you info on how to do that.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dfuel

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on the OpenStreetMap dump idea, here are some notes. You can use [overpass-turbo.eu](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) to quickly check this idea: [example query for Portland, OR](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/5r3), listing 477 nodes, exportable as JSON for further processing. As it is a crowd-sourced dataset, coverage may vary dramatically between regions.

If you want to execute the query for the whole US, export the Query and use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to download the whole dump.